# Selenium - Can't Access Input within Form

Tags: java, forms, selenium

Here is my html that I'm trying to find the input field "j_username", does anyone have a solution, thanks.

```
<head>
    <body>
        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-    WS3MQZ" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
        <script> ..... </script>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
        <div id="pagetoplinks"/>
        <div id="sesMenuFrame">
        <!-- <html> <head> -->
        <script type="text/javascript"> ..... </script>
        <div id="loginframe">
            <div id="loginTitle">
            <div id="EmptyField" class="ui-widget" style="display: none">
            <form id="LoginVal" action="/oam/server/auth_cred_submit" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm('LoginVal')">
                <div id="loginmain" class="bluetable">
                    <div id="j_usernameFormFieldDiv" class="formfield">
                        <div class="labelArea label ">
                        <span class="requiredSpacer"/>
                        <div class="fieldarea">
                            <input id="j_username" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" size="" name="username"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I've tried the following, it finds the iframe, but not j_username by id.

```
driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement( By.tagName( "iframe" ) ) );
driver.findElement( By.id( "j_username" ) ).clear();
driver.findElement( By.id( "j_username" ) ).sendKeys( strUserName );
```

Tried this as well, NoSuchElementException returned for both.

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//input[@id='j_username']" ) );

driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//html/body/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input" ) );
```

Wanted to see where the problem is, finds the div tag before the form in first line, can't find form when added for the second line.

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//html/body/div[3]" ) ); // Finds it - just before form
driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//html/body/div[3]/form" ) ); // NoSuchElementException - for form
```

Tried returning the form element, can't find it by id.

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement( By.id( "LoginVal" ) ); // NoSuchElementException - id of form
form.findElement( By.id( "j_username" ) );
```

Tried returning the form element, finds the form by tagname, but fails on j_username

```
WebElement form = driver.findElement( By.tagName( "form" ) ); // Finds it - form
form.findElement( By.id( "j_username" ) ); // NoSuchElementException - for input
```

Comment: can you show us a bit more of your python code? is the element 'available' on the page, like in 'clickable' or 'present'? (check this page! http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html )

Comment: it's java code, the code before this just goes to the URL that has the above HTML. I'm trying to set the username and password and click on the Login button.  I can't even set the username.  I've also tried this, it finds both the form and the input elements, but I can't set the attribute value of the input element.<br/>   WebElement form = driver.findElement( By.tagName( "form" ) );
      WebElement inp = form.findElement( By.tagName( "input" ) ).;

Comment: yes, element is available on page and visible